# Why is the custom pie chart not displaying? 

Tags: java, swing

Enter text, push button, why does the pie chart does not display?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class PieChart extends JFrame {

    private JTextField jtfParticipation = new JTextField();
    private JTextField jtfProjects = new JTextField();
    private JTextField jtfQuizzes = new JTextField();
    private JTextField jtfFinalExam = new JTextField();
    private JButton jbtCreatePieChart = new JButton("Create Pie Chart");

    public PieChart() {

        // Text panel

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 0));

        panel1.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Input percentages:"));



        // A font to change from the default Plain font to Arial font

        Font arialFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12);

        JLabel jlblParticipation = new JLabel("Participation %");

        JLabel jlblProjects = new JLabel("Projects %");

        JLabel jlblQuizzes = new JLabel("Quizzes %");

        JLabel jlblFinalExam = new JLabel("Final Exam %");



        // The labels use the new font

        jlblParticipation.setFont(arialFont);

        jlblProjects.setFont(arialFont);

        jlblQuizzes.setFont(arialFont);

        jlblFinalExam.setFont(arialFont);



        // Adds the objects to the panel

        panel1.add(jlblParticipation);

        panel1.add(jtfParticipation);

        panel1.add(jlblProjects);

        panel1.add(jtfProjects);

        panel1.add(jlblQuizzes);

        panel1.add(jtfQuizzes);

        panel1.add(jlblFinalExam);

        panel1.add(jtfFinalExam);



        // Assigns the text panel and the button to one panel

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        panel2.add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        panel2.add(jbtCreatePieChart, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        add(panel2, BorderLayout.WEST);



        jbtCreatePieChart.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    }



    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {



        @Override

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



            // Set the size and trigger a repaint

            final PieChartGraphic pie = new PieChartGraphic();

            add(pie, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            pie.setPreferredSize(new Dimension());

            pie.repaint();

        }

    }



    class PieChartGraphic extends JPanel {



        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics slice) {



            super.paintComponent(slice);



            int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;

            int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;

            int radius = (int) (Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4);

            int x = xCenter - radius;
            int y = yCenter - radius;



            double inputIsDouble;

            int inputIsInt;

            int availablePercentage = 100;

            int currentAngle = 0;



            ArrayList<JTextField> jtfs = new ArrayList<>();

            jtfs.add(jtfProjects);

            jtfs.add(jtfParticipation);

            jtfs.add(jtfQuizzes);

            jtfs.add(jtfFinalExam);



            ArrayList<Color> color = new ArrayList<>();

            color.add(Color.RED);

            color.add(Color.GREEN);

            color.add(Color.BLUE);

            color.add(Color.WHITE);



            for (int i = 0; i < jtfs.size(); i++) {

                inputIsDouble = userInput(jtfs.get(i).getText(), availablePercentage);

                inputIsInt = (int) (inputIsDouble * 3.6);

                // Sets the color of the filled

                slice.setColor(color.get(i));

                // Sets the start point and size of the angle

                slice.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, currentAngle, inputIsInt);

                currentAngle += inputIsInt;

                availablePercentage -= inputIsDouble;

            }



            // Places the text strings

            slice.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            slice.drawString("Participation - " +

                "\jtfParticipation.getText() + "%", 1 / 4 * x, 1 / 4 * y);

            slice.drawString("Projects - " + jtfProjects.getText() + "%", 3 / 4 * x, 1 / 4 * y);

            slice.drawString("Quizzes -- " + jtfQuizzes.getText() + "%", 1 / 4 * x, 3 / 4 * y);

            slice.drawString("Final - " + jtfFinalExam.getText() + "%", 3 / 4 * x, 3 / 4 * y);

        }

    }



    public static double userInput(String inputIsString, int availablePercentage) {

        return new Double(inputIsString).doubleValue();

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PieChart frame = new PieChart();

        frame.setTitle("CMIS Pie Chart");

        frame.setSize(334, 215);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setResizable(false);

        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Comment: Good SSCCE for your first post.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to consider:

After creating panel3, the component sizes are never set:

```
panel3.setSize(200, 200);
PieChartGraphic pieChartGraphic = new PieChartGraphic();
pieChartGraphic.setSize(200, 200);
panel3.add(pieChartGraphic);
```

After adding jpanel3, you should call

```
jpanel3.repaint();
```

to paint the Graphics of the added component.

There is user input and validation happening half way through the paintComponent call. This should be done **immediately** before you do any painting, etc.

I've used:

```
public static double userInput(String inputIsString, int availablePercentage) {
    return new Double(inputIsString).doubleValue();
}
```

and can see the Piechart.

Comment: So you're saying you changed my previous method to the above?
Also I am not sure I understand how you are stating it needs to be implemented.  Currently I have it changing the text from the textfield into a double then an integer with it throwing exceptions incase a user inputs anything but a double.  Atleast that's the idea.
Thanks for the advice thus far!

Comment: It still doesn't show for me though.  It just shows a blank box and doesn't actually show a pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a couple problems here.

First is the size/repaint problem @Reimeus pointed out. You need to set the size of the pie chart, and then cause it to be repainted.

Next, the way you add a new PieChartPanel with each button click seems an odd way to do things. You will end up creating new panels that are just stacked on top of each other each time the user presses the button. Why not just have the Pie chart panel permanently added, and just update what is displayed on it, depending on the state?

I changed the following bits of code. First I changed the action listener to remove the extra panel and set a size on the panel. I also added a repaint, although that doesn't seem to matter:

```
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      // Set the size and trigger a repaint
      final PieChartGraphic pie = new PieChartGraphic();
      add(pie, BorderLayout.EAST);
      pie.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 300, 300 ) );
      pie.repaint();
  }
}
```

I then simplified the paintComponent method to remove all of your code:

```
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics slice) {
        super.paintComponent(slice);

        slice.setColor( Color.RED );
        slice.fillRect( 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() );
    }
```

Finally, I changed the JFrame to be resizable. This is an easy way during testing to trigger a repaint. With these changes, when I click on the button, I don't see anything, but if I resize the window, I see the red box.

Comment: My intention is to add the pie chart that was created after the user inputs the values for each text field and uses the button.
I will edit my previous code with my changes implemented.

Comment: Thanks. I did as you suggested but without changing the original PieChartGraphic class.  It did create the pie chart with the specified sizes but as you wrote, it needs to be resized.  Any idea how to correct this so that it shows without forcing a user to resize the window?

Comment: I double checked the fillarc method about the radians as you suggested and it is int angles:

public abstract void fillArc(int x,
           int y,
           int width,
           int height,
           int startAngle,
           int arcAngle)

Comment: Fixed it.
((JFrame)SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JFrame.class, pie)).pack();
This has the window pack itself to the new size after the graphic is painted.

Comment: @Javanoob you are right about the angles/radians, my mistake. I removed that part from my answer.